# Trouble configuring a module in joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-module

I have been searching for a good carousel in joomla and found this one
[SJ Carousel Free](http://www.smartaddons.com/joomla/extensions/free-extensions/item/433-sj-carousel-free-responsive-joomla-module) It also came with a [user guide](http://www.smartaddons.com/joomla/extensions/extension-user-guides/709-sj-carousel-userguide)

I cannot make any sense out of the guide. I want to display a few images from a folder. I have been breaking my head over the "External Path" attribute in the module. It say images/{id}.jpg. What exactly does it mean? Where should I place my images.

I have posted in the official forum but didn't get any answer.
I'd also be grateful if some of you can suggest a few good joomla carousels. I cannot find some easily configurable carousels

Comment: The images folder is the standard Joomla images folder. Presumably you can make a subfolder there.

Answer (score 0):

I gathered that when the module is installed, some sample articles and a category are created which the module is then linked to. You should see how the images are displayed with the sample data. I assume that there is an image with a class and a description within a `<p>` or `<span>` tag in each article. If this is the method used, simple edit the current articles and copy them should you need any more.

The user guide is pretty straight forward. Should you need support, you should really contact the developer of the module else find an extension that is easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need to create a category with articles containing the pictures you want to display. (I think each pic needs to be in a separate article) Then, you select that category in the Data Source box in Source Options Tab, while editing the SJ Carousel module.